# Casting a viewController extracted from an UINavigationController in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, swift

I have `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`. This view controller implement a protocol.

I'm trying to get the first controller of the navigation stack and to cast it :

```
if let vc = _navigationStack.viewControllers?[0] as? ExplorerInterface {
    return vc
}
```

but I get the error :  `Cannot downcast from 'AnyObject?' to non-@objc protocol type 'ExplorerInterface'`.

I'm looking for a way to fix this issue without adding the `@objc` keyword to my protocol (because this protocol contain swift type like tuples and the `@objc` keyword is not compatible with Swift types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form Apple Doc:

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked
>   with the @objc attribute.  Even if you are not interoperating with
>   Objective-C, you need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute
>   if you want to be able to check for protocol conformance.

Check [Swift Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)